# MPAndroidChart PieChart Animations

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I set 2 values on piechart. I want to animate it. But I want to change animation way. All animations do right to left angle. I want to do left to right angle. How can I change animation direction?

**Edit 1**: Library: [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

**Edit 2**: Althought it is not very relevant, I add following code here.

```
mButton_AvailableLimit.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // fromAngle and toAngle is a float variables that less then 360
            mPieChart.spin( 500,fromAngle,360 - toAngle, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuad );
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Metehan please don't assume that every developer knows about MPAndroidChart. Please add link to that library and also add your code to the question.

Comment: MPAndroid library's link added.

Comment: Please add your code too.

Comment: please accept the answer if my solution works.

Comment: Its not. It wont work.

Answer (score 8):

It's very simple in fact,

```
//for rotating anti-clockwise
mPieChart.spin( 500,0,-360f, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuad);
```

Comment: no, its not doing it that way. please inspect the library animations.

Comment: I suggest you to update your MPAndroidChart Library, I'm sure that it works since I just did it.

Answer (score 1):

pieChart.animateX(1000); this is work fine